# Gradient background on a colgroup in IE 10

Tags: css, gradient, internet-explorer-10, linear-gradients

I am trying to use a gradient background in a column using colgroup. This works in all new browsers except for IE10. 
This is my style code:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#ebebeb 100%);
```

The gradient does work on block elements like div.
Is this a bug? Is there a way to fix this?
[image: example]

Comment: I think you need to assign `linear-gradient()` to the `background-image` instead of `background`.